# Why is the verb "did" used in the sentence "I almost did succeed"?

Tags: grammar, sentence-construction

Why is the verb "did" used in the sentence "I almost did succeed"?
Why is the verb "did" used, and not "was"?

Comment: "I almost did succeed" means that **you came very close to succeeding but ultimately fell short or did not completely achieve your goal.**

Comment: Grammatically, the auxiliary verb "did" is used here to **emphasise** the positive polarity of the clause. "Was" can't take the plain form verb "succeed" as complement and hence is ungrammatical.

Answer (score 9):

Did is a complex word with a range of uses in English. It has its own verbal meaning: To do is to carry out an action. ("This morning I did the dishes.").

But it is also used as an auxiliary verb in conjunction with other verbs, and that is what we have here:

1. I almost did succeed.
2. I almost succeeded.

These two sentences have the same basic meaning, except that the use of *did* puts slightly more emphasis on the event (Oh, I was that close, so close!!)

The essential difference between **did** and **was** is that 'did' describes an action (*I did go to the party.*), but 'was' describes a state of being (*I was at the party*). In theory you could use 'was', but you would be saying something different. (*I was almost succeeding at level 10 of the video game when I got interrupted.*)

Comment: Should anyone require a dictionray reference, [do](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/do) *auxiliary verb* 2.

Comment: and to make it even more confusing, you could also say "I did almost succeed", which has yet another meaning! That one takes a more defensive feel, as if in response to an accusation as to why you didn't succeed. "It's true, I had to give up on my marathon 25 miles in. But I did almost succeed, so next year I bet I'll get it."